# Laravel application shows the error: Undefined variable: conferencepackage (View: /var/www/html/example-app/resources/views/products/create.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to PHP and Laravel: I want to implement a dropdown list for conference packages on my show.blade.php page but I get the above error, where would I have gone wrong in my code?

Here is my Web.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    $conferencepackage = App\Models|ConferencePackage::all();
    return view('welcome', ['conferencepackage'=> $conferencepackage]);
});

Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
Route::resource('register', ProductController::class);
Route::resource('adminpannelagmreg', ProductController::class);
Auth::routes();

//I made this a comment
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

My DatabaseSeeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
    $this->call([
        ConferencePackageSeeder::class
    ]);
    }
}
```

My ConferencePackageSeeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ConferencePackageSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
        \DB::table('conference_packages')->insert([
            ['packagename' => 'Training, Conference & Accommodation'],
            ['packagename' => 'Training and Conference Only'],
            ['packagename' => 'Conference and Accommodation Only'],
            ['packagename' => 'Conference Only']
    ]);
    }
}
```

My "show" function in the controller:

```
public function show()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $user = auth()->user();
        $conferencepackages = ConferencePackages::all();
      
        return view('products.show',compact('products', 'conferencepackages'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    
    }
```

My "Show.blade.php" Page (Part where I am trying to implement dropdown):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Conference Package:</strong>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="conferencepackage">
                            <option hidden>Choose Conference Package</option>
                            @foreach ($conferencepackage as $item)
                            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->packagename }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I will appreciate any help and also, if there's any other information needed for me to provide, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In the controller you defined a `conferencepackages` variable, but in the view used a `conferencepackage` variable.
You can rename the variable in controller to `conferencepackage`, or rename in the view.

Rename the variable in the view:

```
@foreach ($conferencepackages as $item)
  <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->packagename }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**OR**

rename the variable in the controller

```
public function show()
    {
        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(20);
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $user = auth()->user();
        $conferencepackage = ConferencePackages::all();
      
        return view('products.show',compact('products', 'conferencepackage'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    
    }
```

Pay attention to variable names, and try to use the **dd()** function to debugging (**@dd()** in view). For example dd out the variable in the controller, so you can check the query results. If the query results is correct the next step is, how you pass the variable to the view check the variable names once more, or try to use the @dd() function

Comment: I have tried to check the variable names but nothing works.